# How to integrate TFS in WebStorm?

Tags: tfs, webstorm, tfvc

I'm using Git with WebStorm's version control already, but have to use TFS version control. After some research fond [this plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/4578-tfs) but there is no tutorial that aiming to configure that plugin.

Can anyone guide me?

Comment: What TFS version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [opt for using `git tfs`](https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs), locally you can still use Git and all of the advantages you're used to. And then push from git to TFVC. You'll need to install [Team Explorer](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=TeamExplorer&rel=16) or the [Team Explorer Cross Platform Commandline Tools](https://github.com/microsoft/team-explorer-everywhere/releases).

Or you can use the native plugin for, the[latest version of the TFS / Azure DevOps (Server) plugin can be found on the Jetbrains site](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7981-azure-devops). It requires TFS 2015 or newer. You can use the plugin you found for older versions of TFS.

A [good explanation to get started can be found here](http://blog.majcica.com/2017/01/02/working-with-tfs-in-intellij-idea-via-vsts-plugin/). The part to configure TFVC is replicated below.

### Visual Studio Team Services plugin and TFVC

Before starting with TFVC, we need an external tool. The tool in question is TF command line tool. It ships with the Microsoft Team Explorer Everywhere 2015 and [you can download it here](https://github.com/microsoft/team-explorer-everywhere/releases).

The file we are interested in is TEE-CLC-14.0.3.zip. Download it and unzip it in a folder of your choice. You should end up with something similar to this.

[image]

Now, open the command prompt, move into the folder where you have extracted the TF command line tool and run the following:

tf eula /accept

If command succeeded and you haven’t received any error, you are good to go.

[image]

Now back to IDEA. Open the settings panel.

[image]

and move to Version Control -> TFVC pane. In the select path to executable field, enter the exact path to the tf.cmd command file located in TF command line tool folder.

[image]

Once done, press the test button and you should see the following message

[image]

Confirm all of the open windows and get back to the IDEA welcome page. Now you are ready to choose Team Services TFVC (Preview) version control.

[image]

At this point, same as for Git, you will be prompted about the connection towards your TFS. The following dialog will be shown.

[image]

Move to the Team Foundation Server tab and specify the address of your TFS server, then click connect. You will now be prompted for the credentials and if everything is ok, you will be shown the list of available TFVC repositories.

[image]

You can now create a new workspace directly from IDEA and start working with your TFVC repositories.

Comment: I'm using WebStorm 2019.1, that hasn't TFVC item in Settings/Version Controls.

Comment: You must first install the plugin: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7981-azure-devops

Comment: Did you read the post to get started? I'd also explains the install procedure.